# Limiting the local stored data size in Android GoogleAnalytics SDK

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have an Android app which tracks usage using the GoogleAnalytics SDK.

This app is used in various network situations, of which some do not have internet connection.

In that case, where there is no internet connection, the GoogleAnalytics data keeps on accumulating.

Is there a way to limit the buffer of locally stored data in GoogleAnalytics  ? 
Or will it just keep on collecting until it hits a system limit and throws an exception ?